# Right way to set Delegate of ScrollView in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, delegates

I have a Custom UITableView Cell as xib.

I have taken an Scroll View inside it.

I Know how to set the delegate but I have confusion.Their is two of doing this.

I don't knw which is best and How to decide which way I have to choose.

> 1 Way : To set Delegate To Files Owner

[image]

> 2 Way : setting Delegate to UITableViewCell

[image]

Comment: Scroll view is the super class of table view.Table view is sub class of Scroll View so you don't need to add scroll inside the tableviee.

Comment: I have to show Image gallery in Mulitple UItable view cells

Answer (score 0):

In a tableviewcell the delegate of scrollview will always be set to UITableViewCell

That means your second step will work .
Let me know if you find any difficulty.

Answer (score 0):

The choice depends on what the delegate function for the inner scroll view must do.  It is simpler to point the delegate to the custom cell and handle the inner scrolling events there.

But if handling that inner scrolling requires a lot of data and logic from the view controller, then point the delegate to the vc.  To make that work, we'll need to know that the scroll event was from an inner scroll view, not the table, and we probably need the row where the scrolling happened, so:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    // if the table view's delegate points here (likely), then to distinguish...
    if (scrollView != self.tableView) {
        // one of the scroll views in the table, but which one?
        NSIndexPath = [self indexPathContainingView:scrollView];
        // here we know that horizontal scrolling happened on indexPath.row
    }
}

// return the indexPath of the tableView cell containing a view
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathContainingView:(UIView *)view {
    while(view && ![view isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell self]])
        view = view.superview;
    return [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)view];
}
```